# Laravel 8 logout confirmation message how to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-8

I have a logout button in my navber.blade.php:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" id="logout" href="{{ route('admin.logout') }}">
    {{ __('Logout') }}
</a>
```

I want that when I click the logout button, it will show me a confirmation message prompting whether you want to logout - (yes or no)? How to do this with jQuery or javascript?

Edit: I have add this jQuery code

```
<script>
        $(document).on("click", "#logout", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var link = $(this).attr("href");
            $.confirm({
                    title: 'Confirm!',
                    content: 'Simple confirm!',
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: function () {
                            $.alert('Confirmed!');
                        },
                        cancel: function () {
                            $.alert('Canceled!');
                        },
                        somethingElse: {
                            text: 'Something else',
                            btnClass: 'btn-blue',
                            keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
                            action: function(){
                                $.alert('Something else?');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
</script>
```

For logout it's showing message

[image]

[image]

But not logging out.

Note: I am just beginner of jQuery

Comment: How about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm ?

Comment: you can try to make your own confirmation box using modal and javascript. And come back here if something goes wrong.

Comment: please check my update

Answer (score 0):

I have missed to added

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

This link